# Add markers in background

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to add markers in the background to prevent the map from becoming non-responsive when adding but I'm seeing an error I've never encountered before.

Here is my attempt to load markers in the background and the error happens when trying to send addMarkerWithOptions.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"yeap im in the background %i, markers=%i", [[self visibleLocations] count], [[[self googleMap] markers] count]);
    for (int i = 0; i < self.visibleLocations.count; i++) {
        Location *location = [self.visibleLocations objectAtIndex:i];
        GMSMarkerOptions *options = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
        options.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([location.lat floatValue], [location.lng floatValue]);
        options.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i) %@", location.mapNeighbors.count, location.title];
        options.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search_measle_small.png"];
        [self.googleMap addMarkerWithOptions:option];
    }
});
```

Error

```
yeap im in the background 860, markers=0
2013-04-20 14:02:11.561 Skate-Spots[7796:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x1d6e7880> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x336a23e7 0x3b39d963 0x336a1ec1 0x16ea0d 0x3b7b7793 0x3b7b75db 0x3b7bae45 0x336761b1 0x335e923d 0x335e90c9 0x371c833b 0x355052b9 0x112e5 0x3b7cab20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view):

> `GMSMapView` can only be read and modified from the main thread, similar
>   to all UIKit objects. Calling these methods from another thread will
>   result in an exception or undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"yeap im in the background %i, markers=%i", [[self visibleLocations] count], [[[self googleMap] markers] count]);
    for (int i = 0; i < self.visibleLocations.count; i++) {
        Location *location = [self.visibleLocations objectAtIndex:i];
        GMSMarkerOptions *options = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
        options.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([location.lat floatValue], [location.lng floatValue]);
        options.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i) %@", location.mapNeighbors.count, location.title];
        options.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search_measle_small.png"];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.googleMap addMarkerWithOptions:option];
      });
    }
});
```